# How can I know if AWS SNS SMS fails?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, sms, amazon-sns

How can I know if AWS SNS SMS fails? I want to use SNS to send phone verification code and I need to know if sending SMS has failed (so I can send it again maybe through another service).

In nexmo for example there are error codes for all kinds of scenarios https://docs.nexmo.com/messaging/sms-api/api-reference#status-codes . I tried searching AWS docs and forums and have not found any  similar feedbacks that allow error handling. I did find reference to CloudWatch usage but I don’t think it fits my use case (or am i missing something?).

I am using PHP sdk.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Successful and failed SMS deliveries are being logged to CloudWatch Logs. So, you can create a Lambda function that gets triggered by CloudWatch Logs to process the event accordingly.

Comment: Indeed Amazon SNS' API is not transparent about failed SMS. Actually, our application receives successful responses of the SNS API, though the sending process results in "Unknown error attempting to reach phone".
https://stackoverflow.com/q/48984636/3514082